# Load assembly to temporary Appdomain from another directory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain

As a part of BaaS project, I need to dynamically execute a code from "guest" assembly. I've tried all the examples and answers in other similar questions including AppDomainToolKit approach, but got no luck.

Similar with the plugin approach, I got positive result by copying related assemblies into host application's bin path. However, this is not possible for the current scenario:

- permissions and restrictions needs to be applied per request
- each request should be evaluated in a temporary appdomain
- load the required assembles and referenced types from a path to temporary domain

So far, my latest piece of code is below

```
        // ClassLibrary1.dll and ClassLibrary2.dll are in the same directory, both are marked as Serializable

        var binPath =  @"C:\AssemblyDemo\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\";
        var lib1Path = binPath + "ClassLibrary1.dll";
        var lib2Path = binPath + "ClassLibrary2.dll";

        var setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        setup.ApplicationBase = binPath;
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("domainname", null, setup);
        ObjectHandle handle = domain.CreateInstanceFrom(lib1Path, "ClassLibrary1.Class1");
        var unwrap = handle.Unwrap();
        var m1 = unwrap.GetType().GetMethod("Method1");
        var result = m1.Invoke(unwrap, null);
```

`handle.Unwrap()` throws exception `Type is not resolved for member 'ClassLibrary1.Class1,ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load the assembly only in the temporary AppDomain you cannot call `Unwrap` in the main domain. `Unwrap` loads the type there as well. You must move all access to objects from the temporary assembly to the temporary AppDomain. You can do this using `AppDomain.DoCallBack` or a custom `MarshalByRef` class that you instantiate in the child domain and call from the parent domain.